# How can I use Nokogiri in irb?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to:

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

in irb, without success. The Nokogiri gem is installed. From:

```
gem list --local
```

I get:

```
nokogiri (1.4.4, 1.4.3.1)
```

but when I try to "require" it in irb, I get:

LoadError: no such file to load -- nokogiri
    from (irb):8:in `require'
    from (irb):8
    from :0

Nokogiri 'lives' in:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/lib
```

on my system.  Also, my GEM PATH (from gem env) is:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

If I go all the way into the nokogiri gem directory, I can successfully "require" it. But why can't I require it from anywhere else?  I am misunderstanding something about the gem path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to `require 'rubygems'` before requiring nokogiri. If there are no witches on your machine this could help.

Comment: "If there are no witches on your machine this could help." Are witches common in machines? How can I tell if my machine has them? Will my machine float in water? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Ruby prior to 1.9 didn't automatically do a `require 'rubygems'` for you. Post 1.9 it does. I always forget when I jump back to 1.8.7 to test something, especially in irb.

You can add `require 'rubygems'` to your `~/.irbrc` file if you want. It won't hurt anything having it there.